# I cant get this conditional update or insert statement to work in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This code is supposed to update a record if the name of the person in table 1 is the same as the name of the person in table 2 and if it is not then just insert the name and age of the person as a new record into table 1.

```
 SELECT
    CASE 
    WHEN
    [Name] = @Name 
    THEN
    UPDATE
    dbo.EmployeeInfo
    SET
    dbo.EmployeeInfo.Age = V.Age 
    FROM dbo.EmployeeInfo I
    INNER JOIN
    dbo.UpdateEmployeeInfo V
    ON
    V.[Name] = I.[Name]

    ELSE

    SELECT * INTO dbo.EmployeeInfo
    FROM dbo.UpdateEmployeeInfo
    WHERE [Name] = @Name

    END
    FROM dbo.EmployeeInfo
```

I have edited the code just to use IF conditions yet it still does not work

```
IF
dbo.EmployeeInfo.[Name] = @Name 
THEN
UPDATE
dbo.EmployeeInfo
SET
dbo.EmployeeInfo.Age = V.Age 
FROM dbo.EmployeeInfo I
INNER JOIN
dbo.UpdateEmployeeInfo V
ON
V.[Name] = I.[Name]

ELSE

SELECT * INTO dbo.EmployeeInfo
FROM dbo.UpdateEmployeeInfo
WHERE [Name] = @Name
```

Comment: Use `IF` for conditional logic inside your queries. `CASE` is simply for modifying result sets inside a SELECT.

Comment: @TZHX I cant get it to work even with IF logic

Comment: You can't use `CASE` as a flow control element. Use `IF` instead. Also, You can't start with a `SELECT` statement and change it into an `UPDATE` statement before completing it. Seems to me like you are looking for `Merge`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> update a record if the name of the person in table 1 is the same as the name of the person in table 2 and if it is not then just insert the name and age of the person as a new record into table 1.

You also could use merge

```
merge table1 as t
using table2 as s
on s.name=t.name
when matched then 
update 
set t.name=s.name
when not matched by target
then
insert (name,age)
values(age,name)
```

Merge has some issues [as per this thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44067/can-i-optimize-this-merge-statement) by Paul White..You could also use seperate statements like below  in a transaction as per your need

```
update t
set t.name=s.name
from table1 t1
join
table2 s
on s.name=t.name

if @@rowcount=0
insert into table1
(name,age)
values
(10,'a')
```